# Push Notifications Request Authorisation Error - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to write error-handling code for when an error occurs when asking for authorization for push notifications. i.e.

```
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { (success, error) in 

        if let error = error {
             // Handle error here
        }
}
```

I'm not sure what type of errors can be returned from this method so I'm unsure about how to handle them.

The docs don't give much information about this either: [https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/asking_permission_to_use_notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649527-requestauthorization)

What can cause an error to happen here and is there an example of one of these errors that get returned?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use the localizedDescription for the same.

```
  if let unwrappedError = error {
      printDebug("error: \(unwrappedError.localizedDescription)")
   }
```

You can also check the error code by the following piece of code.

```
 let errorCode = (error as! NSError).code
```

Let me know in case of any calarification. Enjoy coding!